# Using R or Python, I have to analyze between two excel files

Tags: python, r, analytics

Both the file has same number of columns with same name i.e. Headers, but it differs in row values.(first column rows contains same value) For example Column 1 is over lapping in both the files but other corresponding columns differ.I want to find the difference between two file for overlapping column.

Cheers,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks... for what? What are you asking us for? Do you think anyone'll write code for you _from scratch_? If so, you're wrong. Please provide us with _your attempts to solve this_ and any error messages you encounter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used openpyxl with a lot of success.  You can open the xls files, read your cells, do your math, and generate the new one dynamically.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/